# Why do people mod the bios of his RX 480 card?

Tags: miner-configuration, altcoin

I have a single RX 480 card that I use to mine ethash at miningpoolhub.

On factory settings, I did 24Mhash/s

If I overclock the memory to 2250 MHz, I got 27.5 Mhash/s

Some people say that moding the bios can make things go to 31 Mhash/s

But how?

I can already overclock memory using msi burner. What else can bios mod do that normal overclocking cannot? Technically speaking?

Yes I know, overclocking memory alone won't get me to 31Mhash/s per card. But what is the BIOS mod did internally?